# Generate new matrix from old matrix with specific conditions

Tags: matlab

I have matrix `R(100*100)` and I want to generate new matrix `A(100*100)` as below conditions

If I have a frequency to add a new condition`(let us say frequency = 20)`. This mean I will have five conditions inside my domain `(100/20)=5

```
From 1 to 20, from 21 to 40, from 41 to 60, from 61 to 80, and from 81 to 100.
```

Let us assume my original matrix is

```
 [1 1 1……..1]

 [2 2 2 …….2]

 [3 3 3 ………3]

 And so on

[100 100 100 …..100]
```

The new matrix must be

```
From 1 to 20 same as old matrix

[1 1 1……..1]

[2 2 2 …….2]

[3 3 3………3]

From 21 to 40

A(21,j)=R(21,j)+R(1,j)   (row 21 + row 1)

A(22,j)=R(22,j)+R(2,j)   (row 22 + row 2)

A(23,j)=R(23,j)+R(3,j)   (row 23 + row 3)

And so on

From 41 to 60

A(41,j)=R(41,j)+R(21,j) +R(1,j)  (row 41+row 21 + row 1)

A(42,j)=R(42,j)+R(22,j) +R(2,j)  (row 42+row 22 + row 2)

And so on
A(81,j)=R(81,j)+R(61,j)+R(41,j)+R(21,j)+R(1,j)  (row 81+row 61 + row 41 + row 21+ row 1)
```

At each time that I reach to the frequency, I will have a new condition.
My question is there any sufficient way to do that? I wrote my code and its work fine but each time I change frequency I will have a new condition. For the case above I have `5 conditions` but if I use `frequency 5` I will have `20 conditions` and I need to change all equations. I mean I need code to be able to handle any frequency

I wrote below code

```
clc;
clear;
prompt = 'Enter Frequency=';       %Frequency=20
N= input(prompt);
Frequency=N;
one_step=1/Frequency;              %Frequency
time=Frequency*one_step;
number_of_steps=time/one_step;     %Number of steps until next condition
total_steps=100;
R1 = rand(100,100);
Number_of_Lines=(total_steps/number_of_steps)+1;  %100/20
A(100,100)=0;
    for i=1:100
    for j=1:100
        if i>=1 && i<=number_of_steps
            A(i,j)=R1(i,j);
        elseif i>number_of_steps && i<= 2*number_of_steps
                A(i,j)=R1(i,j)+R1(i-number_of_steps,j);
        elseif i>2*number_of_steps && i<= 3*number_of_steps
                A(i,j)=R1(i,j)+R1(i-number_of_steps,j)+R1(i-2*number_of_steps,j);
        elseif i>3*number_of_steps && i<= 4*number_of_steps
                A(i,j)=R1(i,j)+R1(i-number_of_steps,j)+R1(i-2*number_of_steps,j)...
                    +R1(i-3*number_of_steps,j);
        elseif i>4*number_of_steps && i< 5*number_of_steps
                A(i,j)=R1(i,j)+R1(i-number_of_steps,j)+R1(i-2*number_of_steps,j)...
                    +R1(i-3*number_of_steps,j)+R1(i-4*number_of_steps,j);

        end
end

end
```

Comment: your split seems uneven `From 1 to 19, from 20 to 39,` might be intentional but what do you do for example for `A(39,:)`?

Comment: @karakfa, Thank you so much.You are absolutely right. I changed the splitting, it is even now.Please, how I can make this code general for any frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template and convert to your case

```
rows=100; cols=4; split=5;
x=ones(rows,cols);
c=mat2cell(x,repmat([rows/split],1,split),[cols]);
for i=[2:split]
  c{i,1}=c{i,1}+c{i-1,1};
end;
```

now cells of c contains the sums you need.  Here I used `x` matrix of ones to show the sums are being accumulated, replace with your real matrix.  Also dimension can be derived from the given matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much.